# Receiving data from server in an Android app ruins the rest of the code

Tags: android, jax-ws, ksoap2

I have a problem with my Android Server game. After one player makes his move a request to the server is sent every let's say 3 seconds to check whether the other player made his move so that the first one can move again. Now I have no clue why but no matter how I do it (using Thread.sleep() or the method below) it's like the rest of the code was not there.

```
if (this.filled[field_id] != 0) // The field was already marked
            return;     

        neighbours(field_id); // Colouring neccesary fields

        // Sending updated board to the server:

        if (move>0) {
            filled[field_id] = current;
            GameAndroidUtil.callGameAddMove(session, filled);
            switchColourToOpposite(current); // Switching colour to the opposite as our opponent will now take action
        }                               

        score(); // Updating the score after our move

        if (isBoardFull()){ // Checking if the board is empty
            if(white_score>black_score)
                Toast.makeText(this, "White won!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if(white_score<black_score)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Black won!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "No winner!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Waiting for the opponent to make his move

        boolean different = false;

        while (!different) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            while(endTime!=startTime+3000)
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (checkChange()) {
                different = true;
            }
        }
```

neighbours() and score() should colour the board and then calculate the current score. But they don't. However the array representing the board (filled) is updated properly as it is sent to the server in callGameAddMove(session, filled).

How can that be? I use ksoap2 to send and receive requests to/from server.

Comment: What do u want .. if u r willing to have wait of 3 sec u can use Thread.sleep(3*1000): with the time out.

Comment: That's what I did at first. The result is the same. Previous parts of code are not executed.

Comment: u need to do a different implementation to achieve ur requisite .ie u can write u code in class that implement Runnable and kick it after every three section to do ur network work and then finish it and rest of your code keep on working .